# Using droplist from database set value of another droplist based on the selection of the first one

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this table

```
Device Name    Price
iPhone 6       300
S8             600
```

What I am trying to do is have to drop list one that has all the devices Name and the second has an option "Price" but I want to set its **value** based on the selection of the device name. However, in the drop list it should just display "Price"

I have this php code for the drop lists

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `devicehotsheet`";
$options = "";
$result1 = mysql_query($query, $dbhandle);
while ($row1= mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
$options=$options."<option>$row1[0]</option>";
}
```

For HTML

```
  <select class="selectDevice" id="selectDevice" onChange="calculateTotal()">
          <?php echo $options; ?>
   </select>

  <select class="myport" id="myport" onChange="calculateTotal()">
  <option class="price" value=" ">Price</option>
  </select>
```

I have been trying to do this but so far no luck. I would appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `devicehotsheet`";
$options = "";
$result1 = mysql_query($query, $dbhandle);
while ($row1= mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
$options=$options."<option value='$row1[0]#$row1[1]'>$row1[0]</option>";
}
```

and the javascript code

```
function calculateTotal(){
 var selDev = document.getElementById('selectDevice').value;
 var price = selDev.split('#')[1];
 document.getElementById('myport').innerHTML='<option>'+price+'</option>'
}
```

Comment: How do I use the JS code for real time calculation ? or diplay it as "Total is "

Comment: Scratch the previous question, but could you tell me how you came up with the solution. Like what was you thought process? It would really help me out. Thank you !

Comment: you can use the javascript/jquery for client side calculation if you have the value and items on it, after that you can proceed the server call with ajax to proceed on

Comment: how do i return a value from the selection? return price ?